# Go return struct as JSON in HTTP request

Tags: go

I've defined the following struct in `Go`:

> type repoStars struct {
> name    string
> owner   string
> stars   int
> }

And I've created an array `repoItems := []repoStars{}` which has multiple items of the struct above.

This is how `repoItems` looks like:

[image]

I'm trying to return those items as a JSON response:

```
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(repoItems)
```

And it seems empty

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please read this document: https://yourbasic.org/golang/public-private/ to know more about public and private variables, it's mistake that happens for all of us

Comment: Do not post images of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the struct fields start with a lower case letter it means **unexported**. All unexported fields won't be serialised by the encoder.

Change it to capital first letter.

```
type repoStars struct {
    Name string
    Owner string
    Stars int
}
```

Comment: Please add some information on using JSON tags in Go. By exporting the fields they are indeed marshalled, but they will not be marshalled according to JSON conventions (all lowercase + snake case).